# Can the logit normal distribution be uniquely defined by its first two moments?

Tags: normal-distribution, moments

I was wondering if the logit-normal distribution is uniquely defined by its first two moments; I believe this to be the case as the logit-normal distribution is simply the logit transform of a normal random variable, which is uniquely defined by its first two moments. Furthermore, a reference would be useful.

Thank you!

Comment: Because this distribution family has [two parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution), in principle any two different moments should determine those parameters.  That doesn't prove that the first two moments always uniquely determine the parameters, though: to do that would require some algebra, which is not easy because the moments have no analytical expressions.